# Wordpress multisite and local redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, local, multisite

I am about to start working on another developers site and need to get it running locally.

I have pulled the code and set up a local database running on XAMPP...

It is connecting to the database fine but when I try to try run localhost/site/app

It returns as...
localhost/uk/site/app

I have been told this is because the site it running on a wordpress multisite plugin which redirects automatically based on ip location.

Here is the error on the page...

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.5.37
>   mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

I have hunted for the solution on this but my wordpress knowledge is limited and any help would be appreciated to help me get this running.

Comment: what wordpress multisite plugin? when you figure that out then configure it differently or disable it

Comment: Disable WPMU plugin